# MySQL Workbench EER - show all column in table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, entity-relationship

how can I show all columns in table in EER Model? I've generated EER model from existing database, but one major table is huge (contains plenty of columns) and EER is showing only first 30 cols (and there is a note '28 more ...')

How can I expand them? Because of it, other tables are not connected in the EER, because FK's are missing (hidden) ...

Thank you

Comment: Look for an option that is named "Max. number of columns to display: 30 Larger tables will be truncated" in the preferences under modeling and diagram. It might solve your problem.

Comment: yep this solve the first issue (only part of table visible) .. but it didn't draw the connections ... but thank you anyway :) this IS the answer for my question !! thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In menu bar there is tab called model
2. Then go to Model Options..
3. Then in the model option window select "diagram" option
4. un-tick use defaults from global settings
5. change the value of 'Max. number of columns to display'